# NOT NULL constraint failed null=True blank=True

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

despite having null and blank true in my models I always get

*NOT NULL constraint failed: user_mgmt_profile.user_id*

I've deleted the database, deleted migrations, run commands again, and the error still persist.

Where do you see the issue

Basically Im automatically connecting user to new profile on post request

**models**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gym = models.OneToOneField(Gym, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

**create function in viewset**

```
def create(self, request):
    request.data['user'] = request.user.id
    serializer = ProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        data = serializer.data
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers**

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = '__all__'

class GymSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    place = LocationSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Gym
        fields = '__all__'

class ProfileSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    gym = GymSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

**edit**
I've printed out the

```
request.data['user']
```

and i can see the UUID of the current user

Comment: Are your migrations up to date? e.g. `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate`.

Comment: yeah, I've migrated them couple of times, will run once more just to be sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field is read only, hence that will not work. You need to pass it when saving the object:

```
def create(self, request):
    serializer = ProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(user=request.user)
        data = serializer.data
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```